# Adding 2d sliced arrays of 3d ndarrays crashes python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add large ndarrays which belong to higher dimensional arrays, e.g.,

```
dim1 = 16000
dim2 = 8000
dim3 = 100
a = np.zeros([dim1, dim2, dim3])
a[:,:,1] + a[:,:,2]
```

When I do this, it uses tremendous amounts of memory and the python process gets killed. However, when I try

```
b = np.zeros([dim1, dim2])
c = np.zeros([dim1, dim2])
b + c
```

it works fine.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to overcome this problem?

Thank you

Comment: try a simpler array like np.arange(2*2*3).reshape(2,2,3) to check the addition to see if both return the same result. you aren't comparing the same addition

Comment: They do return the same result when `dim3` is small.  What's confusing me is that although `a[:,:,1]` and `a[:,:,2]` are supposedly ndarrays that have been sliced off of `a`, the addition does not finish and the process just crashes.